# Get all constants from class

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I get CONST's defined on a PHP class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956401/can-i-get-consts-defined-on-a-php-class)

Is it possible to fetch all defined constants from class ?
I.e. I have following class:

```
class Cl {
    const AAA = 1;
    const BBB = 2;
}
```

and I would like to get an array:

```
array (
    'AAA' => 1,
    'BBB' => 2,
)
```