# get all class constants

Tags: php, class, constants

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I get CONST's defined on a PHP class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956401/can-i-get-consts-defined-on-a-php-class)

Is there a way to do get all the constants in a php class. Tried get_class_vars( get_called_class() )

```
    class Status
{        
    const PUBLISHED = "published";
    const DRAFT = "draft";

    public static function get_types()
    {
        return array(self::PUBLISHED, self::DRAFT);
    }
}
```

Thanks