# getting list of constants of child class from the parent in PHP

Tags: php, class, object, inheritance

so suppose I have

```
class B extends A{}
```

and B contains a whole bunch of class constants

Is there a way to define a static function in A that would fetch all class constants in the calling child class?

So for example is there a way to define static function `getChildConstants()` in A

such that if you call `B::getChildConstants()` (B can access this function since B extends A), this function would return all the class constants in B. Moreover, this function must be defined in A only. ie, I don't want to have to reimplement getChildCosntants() in B.

This is so that for any class that extends A, I can easily get the constants of such class without having to reimplement/rewrite/copy and paste getChildConstants() into chose children classes over and over again

so I want a universal constants fetching function in A such that for any class that extends A, I can get the class constants of such class by simply calling this universal constants fetching function that was defined in A

I must reiterate that the getChildConstant() function must be static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to define a function for that. You can use reflection directly on child classes.

```
$reflector = new ReflectionClass('B');
var_dump($reflector->getConstants());
```

Will this satisfy your needs?

[get all class constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3946726/get-all-class-constants)