# "enumeration" class, get all values

Tags: php

I have a class I've written to act like an enumeration:

```
abstract class Enum {
   const VAL1 = "Val1";
   const VAL2 = "Val2";
}
```

I want to define a static function that will return all the constant members of the class but the only function I can find that does that is ReflectionClass::getStaticProperties. Unfortunately it doesn't look like I can use it this way. My understanding is that constants are implicitly static but the function is ignoring them. Is there a method I haven't found that will give me an array of constants in a similar way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I get CONST's defined on a PHP class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/956401/can-i-get-consts-defined-on-a-php-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about [`::getConstants`](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getconstants.php) instead...?

Comment: Talk about the answer being right in front of my face. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) for this.

```
<?php
class Enum {
    const VAL1 = "Val1";
    const VAL2 = "Val2";
}


$refl = new ReflectionClass('Enum');
print_r($refl->getConstants());
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    ['VAL1'] => Val1
    ['VAL2'] => Val2
)
```