# create an array of all constant of a class?

Tags: php, arrays, class-constants

I was working with a class where almost 20 constant are defined, as i want all these constant value in an array, i just want to know

**is there any method which create an array of all constant of a class?**

I tried with [compact](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) BUT it does not work with constants.

```
class Alpha
{
 const ONE = 'fixone'; 
 const TWO = 'fix_two';
 const THREE = 3     
 
   public function __construct()
   {
     protected $arr_constant = compact(ONE,TWO,THREE); // gives FATAL Error
     // is there any method which collect all consant and create an array?
     protected $arr_contact = get_all_constant(__CLASS__); 
     var_dump($arr_constant);
   }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I get CONST's defined on a PHP class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/956401/can-i-get-consts-defined-on-a-php-class)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ref = new ReflectionClass('Alpha');
var_dump($ref->getConstants());
```

Comment: is `ReflectionClass` is inbuilt or default library in php 5+?

Comment: +1 its working perfect. i called `$ref = new ReflectionClass(__CLASS__);` in constructor

Comment: its is mentioned on documents that **This function is currently not documented; only its argument list is available.** May I use this in live project or is there any chances of depreciation

Comment: It's been there for quite a while and deprecation would make little sense, since it's useful and there's no replacement I know of. So yes, it's fine to use. It's simply not well documented, since it's something of a meta-function, the naming is pretty self-explanatory and if you're using it you should know what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

Use: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-constants.php

And: http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getconstants.php

Comment: That gives you *all* constants though, not only specific class constants.

Comment: if we call this function in `Alpha`class then?

Comment: @deceze Added another link for class constants.