# How to tell if a param was passed assuming it was a constant?

Tags: php, constants

I am using this code (note: HELLO_WORLD was NEVER defined!):

```
function my_function($Foo) {
    //...
}

my_function(HELLO_WORLD);
```

`HELLO_WORLD` might be defined, it might not. I want to know if it was passed and if `HELLO_WORLD` was passed assuming it was as constant. I don't care about the value of `HELLO_WORLD`.

Something like this:

```
function my_function($Foo) {
    if (was_passed_as_constant($Foo)) {
        //Do something...
    }
}
```

**How can I tell if a parameter was passed assuming it was a constant or just variable?**

I know it's not great programming, but it's what I'd like to do.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php

Comment: Test if it is defined _before_ you attempt to use it.

Comment: Edited to indicate that `HELLO_WORLD` was NEVER defined in my example, meaning all of the answers that suggest using `defined()` are useless unless I'm missing something.

Comment: I have asked similar question, that may help u : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12174971/create-an-array-of-all-constant-of-a-class

Comment: This is helping : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/956401/can-i-get-consts-defined-on-a-php-class

Comment: Edited again to hopefully explain better what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if a constant isn't defined, PHP will treat it as String ("HELLO_WORLD" in this case) (and throw a Notice into your Log-files).

You *could* do a check as follows:

```
function my_function($foo) {
    if ($foo != 'HELLO_WORLD') {
        //Do something...
    }
}
```

but sadly, this code has two big problems:

- you need to know the name of the constant that gets passed
- the constand musn't contain it's own name

A better solution would be to pass the constant-name instead of the constant itself:

```
function my_function($const) {
    if (defined($const)) {
        $foo = constant($const);
        //Do something...
    }
}
```

for this, the only thing you have to change is to pass *the name* of a constant instead of the constant itself. the good thing: this will also prevent the notice thrown in your original code.

Comment: Your first sentence is the most helpful. I've noticed that undefined constants were converted to strings before, but didn't consider it when asking the question. I think I might just have to think of an alternative way of doing what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
function my_function($Foo) {
    if (defined($Foo)) {
        // Was passed as a constant
        // Do this to get the value:
        $value = constant($Foo);
    }
    else {
        // Was passed as a variable
        $value = $Foo;
    }
}
```

However you would need to quote the string to call the function:

```
my_function("CONSTANT_NAME");
```

Also, this will only work if there is no variable whose value is the same as a defined constant name:

```
define("FRUIT", "watermelon");
$object = "FRUIT";
my_function($object); // will execute the passed as a constant part
```

Comment: He wants to know whether a given param is a constant or a variable

Comment: Ah, I just thought he wanted to know whether it was defined or not.

Comment: @Mr.Alien you are correct. I've updated my question to use better wording.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$my_function ('HELLO_WORLD');

function my_function ($foo)
{
   $constant_list = get_defined_constants(true);
   if (array_key_exists ($foo, $constant_list['user']))
   {
      print "{$foo} is a constant.";
   }
   else
   {
      print "{$foo} is not a constant.";
   }
}
```