# PHP - Treating a class as an object

Tags: php, oop

I need to assign a class (not an object) to a variable. I know this is quite simple in other programming languages, like Java, but I can't  find the way to accomplish this in PHP.

This is a snippet of what I'm trying to do:

```
class Y{

    const MESSAGE = "HELLO";

}

class X{

    public $foo = Y; // <-- I need a reference to Class Y

}

$xInstance = new X();
echo ($xInstance->foo)::MESSAGE; // Of course, this should print HELLO
```

Comment: Why do you need this? Maybe there's a more idiomatic way to accomplish what you want,

Comment: I'm coding a small library and I need to access constants and to call static methods on classes given and run-time. The example above was my simplest way to explain my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that you can treat a reference to a Class just like you would handle any regular String. The following seems to be the simplest way.

Note: In the following snippet I've made some modifications to the one shown in the question, just to make it easier to read.

```
class Y{
    const MESSAGE="HELLO";

    public static function getMessage(){
        return "WORLD";
    }

}
$var = "Y";
echo $var::MESSAGE;
echo $var::getMessage();
```

This provides a unified mechanism to access both constants and/or static fields or methods as well.

Answer (score 3):

In php you cannot store a reference to a class in a variable. So you store a string with class name and use [`constant()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php) function

```
class Y{

    const MESSAGE = "HELLO";

}

class X{

    public $foo = 'Y';

}

$xInstance = new X();
echo constant($xInstance->foo . '::MESSAGE');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use reflection to find it (see [Can I get CONST's defined on a PHP class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956401/can-i-get-consts-defined-on-a-php-class)) or you could a method like:

```
<?php

class Y
{
    const MESSAGE = "HELLO";
}

class X
{
    function returnMessage()
    {
        return constant("Y::MESSAGE");
    }
}

$x = new X();
echo $x->returnMessage() . PHP_EOL;
```

edit - worth also pointing out that you could use [overloading](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php) to emulate this behaviour and have access to a property or static property handled by a user defined method