# Convert PHP class' constant into string

Tags: php, reflection, constants

I have a class with constants like this:

```
class AClass
{
    const CODE_NAME_123 = "value1";
    const CODE_NAME_456 = "value2";
}
```

Is there a way to convert the name of a constant like `AClass::CODE_NAME_123` into a string in order to, e.g., extract the trailing digits from the string?

Comment: How are you planning to refer to what constant it is you need the ID from?

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/956401/can-i-get-consts-defined-on-a-php-class

Comment: @h2ooooooo like this `AClass::CODE_NAME_123`

Comment: @DesmondHume Is this a string? Why do you need to convert it into a string again, if it already is a string? If you already know the constant name, then what's the problem?

Comment: @h2ooooooo not a string ofc

Comment: @DesmondHume But you know the constant name. Then you obviously know the number as well? Are you trying to figure out what constant a specific value has? Can you show the code where you tried something that didn't work? Do you want to extract constants from the class?

Comment: @h2ooooooo there're dozens of constants of this kind that need to be processed according to their names

Comment: @DesmondHume So you want to get the "id"'s of every constant in `AClass` that starts with the string `CODE_NAME_`?

Comment: @h2ooooooo not every, just the one with a specific value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
//PHP's ReflectionClass will allow us to get the details of a particular class
$r = new ReflectionClass('AClass');
$constants = $r->getConstants();

//all constants are now stored in an array called $constants
var_dump($constants);

//example showing how to get trailing digits from constant names
$digits = array();
foreach($constants as $constantName => $constantValue){
    $exploded = explode("_", $constantName);
    $digits[] = $exploded[2];
}

var_dump($digits);
```

Comment: Beat me to it by a second Wayne :-)

Comment: In case anyone needs to see further usage of the ReflectionClass, I'd recommend checking out the unit tests: https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/94e15ff3877f842e5eb5c89e3aeab214fb4a3a33/ext/reflection/tests

Comment: ..that said, it still doesn't do what OP apparently wants: "*just the one with a specific value*"

Comment: @h2ooooooo True, but I just answered the question that he asked. Wasn't until later that he moved the goal posts and wanted the trailing digits of a constant with a specific value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ReflectionClass::getConstants()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getconstants.php) and iterate through the result to find a constant with a specific value, and then get the last digits from the constant name with regex:

```
<?php
    class AClass
    {
        const CODE_NAME_123 = "foo";
        const CODE_NAME_456 = "bar";
    }
    
    function findConstantWithValue($class, $searchValue) {
        $reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass($class);
        foreach ($reflectionClass->getConstants() as $constant => $value) {
            if ($value === $searchValue) {
                return $constant;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    function findConstantDigitsWithValue($class, $searchValue) {
        $constant = findConstantWithValue($class, $searchValue);
        if ($constant !== null && preg_match('/\d+$/', $constant, $matches)) {
            return $matches[0];
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    var_dump( findConstantDigitsWithValue('AClass', 'foo') ); //string(3) "123"
    var_dump( findConstantDigitsWithValue('AClass', 'bar') ); //string(3) "456"
    var_dump( findConstantDigitsWithValue('AClass', 'nop') ); //NULL
?>
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/76182)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ReflectionClass()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php) and loop through the resulting keys applying a `preg_match` to each value to extract the last 3 numbers of the string:

```
class AClass
{
    const CODE_NAME_123 = "";
    const CODE_NAME_456 = "";
}

$constants = new ReflectionClass('AClass');

$constants_array = $constants->getConstants();

foreach ($constants_array as $constant_key => $constant_value) {
   preg_match('/\d{3}$/i', $constant_key, $matches);
   echo '<pre>';
   print_r($matches);
   echo '</pre>';
}
```

The output would be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 123
)
Array
(
    [0] => 456
)
```