# PHP Class constant with php function constant giving warning

Tags: php, constants, class-constants

I have a constants I want to return by a function like this:

```
public function getConst($const)
{
    $const = constant("Client::{$const}");
    return $const;
}
```

But this is giving me an error:

```
constant(): Couldn't find constant Client::QUERY_SELECT
```

This however, does work:

```
public function getConst($const)
{
    return Client::QUERY_SELECT;
}
```

Why not?

Comment: You could try a reflection class.

Comment: Aha! That's great. That works! If you give an answer I can mark it as answered.

Comment: Nah this question is probably a duplicate anyways. Glad it worked though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I get CONST's defined on a PHP class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/956401/can-i-get-consts-defined-on-a-php-class)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact this works just fine: http://3v4l.org/pkNXs

```
class Client {
    const QUERY_SELECT = 'foo';
}

$const = 'QUERY_SELECT';
echo constant("Client::{$const}");  // foo
```

The only reason this would fail is if you're in a namespace:

```
namespace Test;

class Client {
    const QUERY_SELECT = 'foo';
}

$const = 'QUERY_SELECT';
echo constant("Client::{$const}");  // cannot find Client::QUERY_SELECT
```

The reason for that is that string class names cannot be resolved against namespace resolution. You have to use the fully qualified class name:

```
echo constant("Test\Client::{$const}");
```

You may use the `__NAMESPACE__` magic constant here for simplicity.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I'm in a namespace. That must have been the problem. Right now I use reflection and it's working too.

Comment: But surely this is working too: return constant('Solarium\Core\Client\Client::' . $const);

Comment: Unfortunately, `__NAMESPACE__` doesn't help if I'm in another namespace than the class with the constant which I want to refer to with an alias (using `use`).

Comment: @Jānis Yeah, then you need to use the fully qualified class name.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the ReflectionClass, it would work.

```
$reflection = new ReflectionClass('Client');
var_dump($reflection->hasConstant($const));
```

More verbose example, it might be over kill ( not tested )

```
public function getConst($const)
{
   $reflection = new ReflectionClass(get_class($this));
   if($reflection->hasConstant($const)) {
     return (new ReflectionObject($reflection->getName()))->getConstant($const);
   }
}
```