# Converting integer back to constants

Tags: php

Suppose I have the following array

```
$options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );
```

When I do `var_dump($options)`

`array(2) { [12]=> bool(true) [3]=> int(2) }`

However I want the predefined constant to display like `PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT` not as `12`

Comment: That’s not possible. Imagine instead of constants, you were using variables – then you would not expect the var_dump output to show the variable name either, but the only thing that makes sense – the value.

Comment: 1) Why? 2) The constants just correspond to some value which you see in the output

Comment: Why can't you just later call $options[PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT] (or any other key that is available in the `$options`)? It will evaluate to $options[12], and return `true`.

Comment: maybe useful? [Can I get CONST's defined on a PHP class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/956401/can-i-get-consts-defined-on-a-php-class). e.g. : `$refl = new ReflectionClass('PDO'); print_r($refl->getConstants());` . You may need to filter  them to limit them to the  ones you actually want but that would be easy to do?