# How to get the value of a constant and save it to the database

Tags: php, arrays, constants

I have a constant class like so

```
Class MyConstants
{
const TEST = "asd";
const TEST123 = "foo";
const TEST333 = "fooBar";
const TEST321 = "bar";
}
```

In my controller I get all constants and select 3 at random, the problem is I only get the key from the constant but I need the value

```
$allConstants = $this->getAllConstants();
$foo = array_rand($allConstants, 3);

dd($foo)

 array:3 [
  0 => "TEST321"
  1 => "TES"
  2 => "TEST123"
 ]
```

How can i get instead the value of the constant which for example would be foobar ?

I also then need to save them to the database. Should i Loop over them ?

```
$fooBarEntity->setData($foo);
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of : [Can I get CONST's defined on a PHP class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956401/can-i-get-consts-defined-on-a-php-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[array_flip](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) exchanges all keys with their associated values in an array.
Try this:

```php
Class MyConstants
{
    const TEST = "asd";
    const TEST123 = "foo";
    const TEST333 = "fooBar";
    const TEST321 = "bar";
}

$reflection = new ReflectionClass(MyConstants::class);
$values = $reflection->getConstants();
$data = array_rand(array_flip($values), 3);
foreach($data as $item) {
    #$fooBarEntity->setData($item);
}
print_r($data);
```

Comment: Remember to always exercise caution when using `array_flip()`, as if the same value is present multiple times in the array, every corresponding key except the last one will be lost.